# MongoDB performant nested query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm having a collection in MongoDB with documents that among others contain the keys `item_id` and `date`:

```
|---------------------|----------------------|
| item_id             | date                 |
|---------------------|----------------------|
| 53b8f34e            | 2019-08-12 14:02:05  |
|---------------------|----------------------|
| 53b8f34e            | 2019-08-12 14:04:31  |
|---------------------|----------------------|
| 53b8f34e            | 2019-08-12 14:06:21  |
|---------------------|----------------------|
| d8231f82            | 2019-08-12 14:01:55  |
|---------------------|----------------------|
| d8231f82            | 2019-08-12 14:03:31  |
|---------------------|----------------------|
| d8231f82            | 2019-08-12 14:04:51  |
|---------------------|----------------------|
```

There is an index on `date` and a compound index on `item_id` and `date`. The typical workload would be hundreds of distinct item IDs with each item ID having thousands of records.

For each distinct `item_id`, I need to fetch the record with the most recent date.

The following aggregate gives me the desired result. It is very slow, however, multiple seconds for 4 item IDs and a few 100k records. `.explain()` shows that the aggregate does not use any index and simply does a full table scan.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group":
        {
            "_id": "$item_id",
            "max_date": {
                "$max": "$date"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Manually querying the distinct item IDs from the application is quite a bit quicker, but very inefficient due to the many roundtrips to the database:

```
db.collection.distinct("item_id")

for each item_id in result:
    db.collection.find({item_id: <item_id>}).sort({date:-1}).limit(1)
```

Is there a way to do this nested / subquery in a single MongoDB query in a way that makes use of indexes?